# Why does the execution of Gradle task assembly debug fail with Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Launching `lib/main.dart` on `sdk gphone64 arm64` in `debug mode`...
Running Gradle task `assembleDebug`...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- This is the error output:

```
Execution failed for task ':fluttercontactpicker:parseDebugLocalResources'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':fluttercontactpicker:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes{ 
  artifactType=android-platform-attr,
  org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,
  org.gradle.usage=java-runtime
}.

Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: 
/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar.
/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-32/android.jar
```

- I tried to run it with

  - `--stacktrace` option to get the **stack trace**.
  - `--info` or `--debug` option to get **more log output**.
  - `--scan` to get **full insights**.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.4, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64, locale en-PS)
    • Flutter version 3.10.4 on channel stable at 
      /Users/mac/Developer/flutter
      ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to 
      /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.10.4/flutter/bin/flutter, 
      which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at 
      /Users/mac/Developer/flutter. 
      Consider adding /Users/mac/Developer/flutter/bin 
      to the front of your path.
      ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to 
      /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.10.4/flutter/bin/dart, 
      which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at 
      /Users/mac/Developer/flutter. 
      Consider adding /Users/mac/Developer/flutter/bin 
      to the front of your path.
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 682aa387cf (3 months ago), 
      2023-06-05 18:04:56 -0500
    • Engine revision 2a3401c9bb
    • Dart version 3.0.3
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings; 
      however it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update   
      checks and upgrades.
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammed, I tried to understand your problem and tried to clean up the phrasing of your question but I am not sure I got it right, can you please clarify your question? The scope shall be clear in the header and note down what you tried already. - thank you!